# Removing name.middleName with "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"

Tags: json, oim, scim2

I would like to remove the attribute `name.middleName` with patch operation

```json
{
    "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op":"remove",
            "path":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User:name.middleName"
        }
    ]
}
```

and HTTP method `PATCH` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/identity-governance/12.2.1.4/omdev/developing-and-customizing-applications-oracle-identity-governance.pdf). But it doesn't work. The server sends status 200 but nothing has happened. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your request looks valid, but Oracle Identity Manager may not support the use of fully-qualified attribute names in the path. If OIM does not support this, then it is likely looking for an attribute that is actually named `urn...` on the resource, so the service provider would consider this an invalid attribute in this case. Some REST APIs will ignore references to invalid attributes for version incompatibility reasons, which would explain why it returns an HTTP 200 instead of an error message.

I would try providing `"path": "name.middleName"` in the request and see if that works.